# PDO SHOW TABLES array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Just working with this function and it's not working out as planned. It is supposed to grab all table names in a database and store them in an array. However the results of the array is doubling up the array shown in the example below:

```
Array ( [0] => 113340 ) 
Array ( [0] => 113340 [1] => 116516 ) 
Array ( [0] => 113340 [1] => 116516 [2] => 139431 ) 
Array ( [0] => 113340 [1] => 116516 [2] => 139431 [3] => 20731 ) 
Array ( [0] => 113340 [1] => 116516 [2] => 139431 [3] => 20731 ... )
```

The code that I am using:

```
function itemDiscontinued($dbh, $id, $detail) {
  try {
    $tableList = array();
    $result = $dbh->query("SHOW TABLES");
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
      $tableList[] = $row[0];
      print_r($tableList);
    }
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 to remove the downvote someone added. There is nothing wrong with this question, it is a simple error in the code. The user has shown research and effort in producing the question so absolutely no need to downvote!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

to get all names of the tables this is much better

```
public function list_tables()
{
    $sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
    if($this->is_connected)
    {
        $query = $this->pdo->query($sql);
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the array in the while loop! This will print it each time you add an item to it from the recordset. Instead you need to print it once it has completed populating like so:

```
function itemDiscontinued($dbh, $id, $detail) {
    try {   
        $tableList = array();
        $result = $dbh->query("SHOW TABLES");
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
            $tableList[] = $row[0];
        }
        print_r($tableList);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh so silly! I'm still learning here but anyways thank you so much Ben!

Comment: @DrDogN Not at all. The simplest errors are always the hardest to spot! :-)