# List all the tables in your MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a hard time trying to list all the tables in my database.

---

## I tried

```
<?php 

//Configuration
$dbname      = 'local';
$user        = 'root';
$host        = '127.0.0.1';
$pass        = '';
$date        = date('Y-m-d');
$export_type = 'mysql'; // option : mysql | psql
$file_name   = $date.'-portal';
$file_path   = $file_name;



// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($res != false){

    echo "Connected successfully";
    $FILE = fopen("output.csv", "w");

    $table = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
       $table[] = $row['0'];
    }

    foreach($tables as $table) {
        $columns = array();
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            $columns[] = "$row[0]";
        }
        fwrite($FILE, implode(",", $columns)); fwrite("\n");
        $resTable = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $table");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resTable, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            fwrite($FILE, implode(",", $row)); fwrite("\n");
        }
    }
}else{
    die(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

---

## Result

```
if($res != false){
//.. everything in here never get executed
}

`$res` kept returning `false`.
```

---

What did I do wrong that could have lead to this ?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` should be `mysqli_fetch_array`, `mysql_error` should be `mysqli_error($conn)`. Any better?

Comment: The PDO version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27467588/4357238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use db in your connection

```
 mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
```

And use query like this

```
 $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
```

Comment: Works. My `$res` variable now return true. But do you know how to fix `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource object given` ?

Comment: Check mysqli you took mysql not mysqli here

Comment: I'm accepting your answer. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Last, question, I promise, do you know why `$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");` keep returning false. Did I do anything unusual again ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql

Answer (score 3):

You can always execute the query:

```
Show tables;
```

After you selected database.

By the way you also can execute:

```
Show databases;
```

To list all of the databases your current user has permission to view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass through your database in the connection script.

Like so:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $dbname);
```

Then, when you want to pull rows from a table, you do it like this:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT rows FROM table");
```

One of the reasons this wasn't working for you was because you weren't passing through your database name through the connection. Also, rather than doing the above query, you selected a table from a database; rather than a row from a table.

Also, I noticed that you're using the `mysql_*` error output on the last line.

Comment: First, I want to query all the tables in my database, Not all the rows in my table.

Comment: Second, I've added the `$dbname` as my fourth arguments and my $res variable still returning `false` - and that still preventing my entire block of code from executing.

Comment: I'm well aware of this. You have to do this another way. There are various sources specifying how to do so. Also, you can change which rows you would like to select. I used `SELECT *` just as an example

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version

Changes:

- Added `$dbname` to `mysqli_connect` function
- Added the backtick ` char between the table names, to avoid errors with  reserved keyword from MySQL
- Changed mysql_ functions to mysqli_
- Close the file
- Close the connection

[Here](http://pastebin.com/B3jZ4wc9) is the code

**NOTE:** sorry I don't why, but when I pasted the code in the answer, all de code identation was messed up, even trying to indent it properly, I wasted like 10 minutes :(